# How do I add a new value in each row of my json

Tags: php, json, ajax

How do I add a new value to each row of my JSON. I'm currently pulling multiple rows of data and storing in a variable that I'll turn into JSON to be returned in my ajax call but I want to add one more value into each row.

This is my php code. I want to change json before I encode it to add another value called `mark` that stores an int to each row.

```
 if($json = mysqli_fetch_all ($stmt, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

        } else{
            $json['max'] = true;
        }
         echo json_encode($json);
```

This is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
       url: "infinite.php",  
       method: "POST",
       data: {start: start, reachedMax: reachedMax},
       dataType: "JSON",                   
       success: function(data){
           if(data.max || reachedMax){
                reachedMax = true;
                return;
           }     


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a foreach loop right after you retrieve the database result. In this loop you add new values to all elements:

```
if ($json = mysqli_fetch_all($stmt, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    foreach (array_keys($json) as $key) {
        $json[$key]['mark'] = 23;
    }

} else {
    $json['max'] = true;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```